# MySQL error 1674 even when binlog is set to ROW

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter table by doing,

```sql
ALTER TABLE Account
ADD `AccessCode` binary(16) NOT NULL  DEFAULT (UUID())
```

It gives me error,

```
Error Code: 1674. Statement is unsafe because it uses
a system function that may return a different value on the slave.
```

My Binlog format is `Row`

```sql
show variables like 'binlog_format'

--------------------------
|Variable_name  |  Value |
--------------------------
|'binlog_format'| 'ROW'  |
--------------------------
```

Though I will find some alternative, but why it is not allowing me? Even after setting binlog format as `ROW`, what is the problem here?

Comment: As almost pointed out in the first Answer, the default you provide will be truncated from 36 bytes to 16.  This is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` statements are still replicated as statements. Even with `binlog_format=ROW` this will be requiring the existing table populate the existing rows with an `AccessCode`.

I recommend:

```
ALTER TABLE Account ADD AccessCode binary(16) NOT NULL;
UPDATE Account SET AccessCode = UUID_TO_BIN(UUID());
```

[This manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-add-drop-column) says that non-determinstic default functions on columns may produce a warning or error (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` was an exception).

I'm not sure you can create this, even on the master after executing `SET SESSION sql_log_bin=0; ALTER TABLE Account Alter AccessCode SET DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))`, I tried MySQL-8.0 however your version may differ.

Comment: It will not work, because `ALTER TABLE` does not have default value, also if I set default to zero and do UPDATE later on, there is no way to set default for future inserts that will not supply AccessCode. This will require rewrite of lot of code that didn't use AccessCode. Problem is I am migrating my app from MS SQL to My SQL and it is little pain.

Comment: A dodgy way be be to use triggers to populate this field.